# Capturing Pre-execute Event in Symfony/Doctrine DBAL

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am looking for a way to interject and modify/wrap queries before they are sent from Doctrine/Symfony to Postgres. I've been looking around at Symfony's and Doctrine's standard events ([here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.4/namespace-Doctrine.DBAL.Event.html) and [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/events.html) is what I found), but there doesn't seem to be any generic "before execute query" event.

Is this a lost cause/even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean if you do `$class->setName('abc');` in controller/service/etc and then just before persisting into DB, you want to do something like `if (whatever whatever) { `$class->setName('new value');` } and persist? Am I understanding right?

Comment: No, I don't want an object lifecycle event trigger, I want to tag the query before it goes to the db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use a wrapper class thanks to the *wrapper_class* parameter when configuring your connections ?

[See here for more info about Doctrine DBAL's configuration](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)

Basically, it permits you to implement a custom *Connection* class. What you could do is create a custom *Connection* class inheriting from the original one (*\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection*) and override the *executeQuery()* method. There, you could use your own event management implementation to throw an event or use the built-in *EventManager*.